# If $PA - PB = \text{constant}$ then the locus of $P$ will be a hyperbola.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

The sound of a cannon firing is heard one
second later at a position B than at position A.
If the speed of sound is uniform, then

(A) The positions A and B are foci of a
hyperbola, with cannon's position on one
branch of the hyperbola

(B) the position A and B are foci of an ellipse
with cannon's position on the ellipse

(C) One of the positions A,B is focus of a
parabola with cannon's position on the
parabola

(D) It is not possible to describe the positions
of A, B and the cannon with the given
information

**My Attempt:** If I suppose the position of A and B are respectively $(c,0)$ and $(0,-c)$ and $2a = 343\ $m, then we will get the locus of $P$ as follows $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{(c^2 - a^2)} = 1~.$$
If $c^2 > a^2$ we are done but if not then what will happen?

Explicitly saying if the speed of the sound is greater than the distance between two points then what will happen?

Can anyone please help me  if I have gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: Your foci should be $(c,0)$ and ($-c,0$), see my updated answer for the complete proof.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** This was my first answer to the original question. OP change his question afterward, so I'll update my answer.

The geometric definition of an hyperbola is :

> the points such that the difference of the distance to two foci is
>   constant. This difference is equal to the distance between the apex of the hyperbola

If A and B are the foci, the cannon is somewhere on an hyperbola.

---

The geometric definition I gave is equivalent to the following algebric definition of the horizontal hyperbola

> If the foci of the hyperbola are located at $(c, 0)$ and $(-c, 0)$, then the hyperbola is given by the equation $$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \qquad \text{where }c^2 = a^2+b^2$$

**Proof**

Starting with the geometric definition.  Let $A(c, 0)$ and $B(-c,0)$, the foci, and $P(x, y)$ a point on the hyperbola. Then, the difference of the distances is equal to $2a$.
$$\vert d(P, A) - d(P, B)\vert = 2a$$
$$\left\vert \sqrt{(x-c)^2+(y-0)^2} - \sqrt{(x-(-c))^2+(y-0)^2}\right\vert = 2a$$
If we square each side, it become
$$(x-c)^2+y^2 - 2\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2} + (x+c)^2+y^2 = 4a^2$$
Developping the $(x\pm c)^2$ and moving things around give us
$$x^2+y^2+c^2-2a^2=\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}$$
We square once again to get rid of square roots.
$$(x^2+y^2+c^2-2a^2)^2=((x-c)^2+y^2)((x+c)^2+y^2)$$
Developping both side
$$x^4+y^4+c^4+4a^4 + 2x^2y^2+2x^2c^2-4a^2x^2+2y^2c^2-4a^2y^2-4a^2c^2 = x^4-2x^2c^2+c^4+y^4+2y^2x^2+2y^2c^2$$
Cancelling terms on each side and reorganise remaining terms
$$4a^4+4x^2c^2-4a^2x^2-4a^2y^2-4a^2c^2 = 0$$
$$x^2(c^2-a^2)-a^2y^2=a^2(c^2 - a^2)$$
Since $c^2 = a^2+b^2$
$$x^2b^2-a^2y^2=a^2b^2$$
Dividing everywhere by $a^2b^2$
$$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

A similar proof could be done for a vertical hyperbola $\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}-\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}=1$

Comment: How can you please give a proper proof? I am finding the proof.

Comment: This is just what OP is trying to prove, from the algebraic definition.

Comment: @URL OP change his question after I posted my answer. I'll edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If $2a$, as in your answer, is the distance covered by sound in a second, then $PB-PA=2a$. But triangular inequality gives $AB\ge PB-PA$, that is $c\ge a$. If $c=a$ then you get a degenerate hyperbola consisting of two rays.

Comment: you are right, I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

A very broad hint: if the distance between the two points is less than the distance sound travels in a second (be careful with your phrasing; you can't compare a *speed* with a *distance*, as you try to do in your comment on that case), then what does the triangle inequality tell you about the relative distances from P to A and B, and what does that imply for the temporal gap between the two events?

Answer (score 0):

*Three* points (listening posts, foci) are needed. Their coordinates  (A,B,C) are known. Time differences $(T_{AB},T_{BC})$ are also known.

$2c$ is interfocal distance for first hyperbola.

$$ 2a= T_{AB}\cdot v\,;\quad  \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{(c^2 - a^2)} = 1 ;$$

We plot *both* hyperbola branches on graph paper to find point of intersection as the cannon location point $P$ for listening posts $( S_1,S_2,S_3 )$ instead of $(A,B,C).$ 
Only one branch which heard the bang at first needs to be plotted or taken into calculation for intersection.

[image: SundRanging]